# *any fuction* "is not a function" Reactjs fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

i've tried to make a fetch and take one element of the data base by id on Reactjs, backend with javascript(node + express + sequelize), but i had some problems and i couldn't at anytime. im searched on google but i dont know hot to apply the solutions on my code... here some examples of my trying:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { useParams, Link } from "react-router-dom";

import "./detallesBarrio.css";

const BarriosDetails = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const [barrio, setBarrio] = useState({});

  const loadBarrioDetails = () => {
    fetch("http://localhost:3001/api/barrios")
      .then((x) => x.json())
      .then((y) => y.data)
    //   .then((z) => console.log(z))
      .then((allBarrio) => setBarrio(allBarrio));
  };
  
let byid = barrio.filter(obj => {
    return obj.id === id;
});
 console.log(byid);

  loadBarrioDetails();

  return (
    <main className="barrio-details">
      {byid.map(obj => {
        return (
          <div key={obj.id}>
            <div>
              <h1>Detalles de {obj.nombre}</h1>
              <img src={obj.foto} alt="imagen no disponible" />

              <article>
                <Link to="/barrios">Volver</Link>
              </article>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </main>
  );
};

export default BarriosDetails;
```

also my tryings:

-no filter function (problem: map is not a function)

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { useParams, Link } from "react-router-dom";

import "./detallesBarrio.css";

const BarriosDetails = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const [barrio, setBarrio] = useState({});

  const loadBarrioDetails = () => {
    fetch(`http://localhost:3001/api/barrios`)
      .then((x) => x.json())
      .then((y) => y.data)
    //   .then((z) => console.log(z))
      .then((allBarrio) => setBarrio(allBarrio));
  };

  loadBarrioDetails();

  return (
    <main className="barrio-details">
      {barrio.map((barri) => {
        return (
          <div key={barri.id}>
            <div>
              <h1>Detalles de {barri[id].nombre}</h1>
              <img src={barri[id].foto} alt="imagen no disponible" />

              <article>
                <Link to="/barrios">Volver</Link>
              </article>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </main>
  );
};

export default BarriosDetails;
```

-no maping (problem: the code dont recognise 'nombre'(database camp') on '{barrio[id].nombre}')

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { useParams, Link } from "react-router-dom";

import "./detallesBarrio.css";

const BarriosDetails = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const [barrio, setBarrio] = useState({});

  const loadBarrioDetails = () => {
    fetch(`http://localhost:3001/api/barrios`)
      .then((x) => x.json())
      .then((y) => y.data)
      .then((z) => console.log(z))
      .then((allBarrio) => setBarrio(allBarrio));
  };

  loadBarrioDetails();

  return (
    <main className="barrio-details">
      <div>
        <h1>Detalles de {barrio[id].nombre}</h1>
        <img src={barrio[id].foto} alt="imagen no disponible" />

        <article>
          <Link to="/barrios">Volver</Link>
        </article>
      </div>
    </main>
  );
};

export default BarriosDetails;
```

> yes console.log give me the correct array

Comment: Should it be `useState([])` instead of `useState({})`? You are setting the initial value of `barrio` as an object instead of array

Comment: and first check byid.length && byid.map(() => ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You are getting map is not a function because you're initiating the state as an object. is should be `useState([])` instead of `useState({})`
- based on your code you want to filter by id and id is unique so it's better to use `array.find(obj => obj.id === id)` than using `array.filter()`.
- in your first snippet `let byid = barrio.filter(obj => { return obj.id === id; });` is executed before running the fetch and loading data.

try using `useEffect` for this kind of needs and loading data as a side effect after mounting the component and you should check the existance of an object or array before accessing it   `useEffect(() => loadBarrioDetails(), [])`

**Or since you just need one single object you can use like this:**

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { useParams, Link } from "react-router-dom";

import "./detallesBarrio.css";

const BarriosDetails = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const [barrio, setBarrio] = useState(null);

  const loadBarrioDetails = () => {
    fetch(`http://localhost:3001/api/barrios`)
      .then((x) => x.json())
      .then((y) => y.data)
      .then((allBarrio) => {
        const byId = allBarrio.find(obj => obj === id);
        setBarrio(byId ?? null);
    });
  };

useEffect(() => loadBarrioDetails(), []);


if (!barrio) return <></> // anything to display that the data is loading or doesn't exist depends on you need.
  return (
    <main className="barrio-details">
      <div>
        <h1>Detalles de {barrio.nombre}</h1>
        <img src={barrio.foto} alt="imagen no disponible" />

        <article>
          <Link to="/barrios">Volver</Link>
        </article>
      </div>
    </main>
  );
};

export default BarriosDetails;
```

Comment: thanks! i made it work thanks to a friend and you were right! i made it without that unnecessary 'byid'

`
  useEffect(() =>   {
    fetch(`http://localhost:3001/api/barrios`)
      .then((x) => x.json())
      .then((y) => {
        const data = y.data
        const barri = data.find(b =>b.id===Number(id))
        console.log(id, data);
        setBarrio(barri)
       })
  }, [id]);


  return (

      {barrio && barrio.foto && barrio.nombre &&(

        <img src={barrio.foto} alt="imagen no disponible" />

`